# Set react native global variable from Xcode

Tags: react-native

I saw that there is the `__DEV__` variable, and I would like to add my own, say `__USE_THIS__`. Then way I set this is when the Xcode project is building, but I don't know how to pass that to the js part. Can I use the bundle script and pass it there somehow? When is the `__DEV__` set, and how?

Comment: you want ot pass a variable value to the js file?

Comment: thi looks somehow related: https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config

Comment: I want to pass something like `__USE_THIS__ = true`, and in that case the js will do something different than if it was false (by default).

Comment: I checked the react-native-config, but that uses `.env`, and that means I will pass those everywhere. I would be happy with a simpler way of just passing something one-way from xcode to js.

Answer (score 4):

You could have Target/Scheme specific variables exposed to javascript by writing them to a file during Build Phase and then import them in the javascript.

1) Add the following to "Bundle React Native code and images" under "Build Phase" for your target:

```
export NODE_BINARY=node
echo '{"target": "MyTarget"}' > ../build-info.json
../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh
```

[Example screenshot from xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uau4W.png)

2) Import them in the javascript, for example in index.ios.js

```
import buildInfo from '../../build-info.json'
console.log(buildInfo.target)
```

It should also be possible to write a file to $PROJECT_ROOT/.env and use it through something like [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) instead if you prefer